# Glide Load Image Not Complte

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

[A loading Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9HjY.gif) And I use Glide to load Gif, And the third bar show to me is not complete, It show white area in third bar which is not be shown.(English is poor, sorry), like this[Error Showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9HjY.gif)  Dear all, How can I solve it?

```
 ScaleType="fitXY"
 Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.loading).into(imageView);
```

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9HjY.gif): [image]

Comment: Gifimageview https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Answer (score 2):

use GifImageView

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/src_anim"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_anim"
    />
```

[Android-Gif-Drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)

Comment: Thank you very much.But actually I only want to use glide. I didn't want to import another lib.  Thank you

Comment: glide to loading image fro \m server and GifImageView to showing image like GIF

Comment: The gif is in res/drawable folder already, I just want to show it in imageView

Answer (score 1):

### Steps to load Gif images from drawable

1. **You need to move your `loading` Gif image to`res/raw` folder of your project** 
   (
   if your project don't have `raw` folder in resource directly then simply make one and put your gif in it )
2. **and then you can simply load your gif with just one line of code**

> ```
> Glide.with(this)
>                   .load(R.raw.loading)
>                   .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(
>                           (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image)));
> ```

Edits:-

White area in Gif image could be becaouse of streatching gif this is how it look like in my device

[image]

Alternatively you can look into this open source library for  loading animation

https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. The gif is animated，but the third bar in the gif have a white area, like this :  [error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5aiQ5.png)

Comment: Thank you very much!   I will try your suggestion!